# Sorting Authors Widget According To Last Activity

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sorting

I have a Wordpress widget and it lists top authors according to post count.
I want it to sort as last activity (last post). But i can't.
My code is:

```
 "SELECT users.ID, COUNT( posts.ID ) AS post_count
  FROM {$wpdb->users} AS users
   RIGHT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts ON posts.post_author = users.ID 
   WHERE posts.post_type='post' AND posts.post_status='publish'
   GROUP BY users.ID 
   ORDER BY post_count DESC 
   LIMIT %d"`
```

Output:

[image]

How can i sort the authors according to last post?

Comment: Please don't post links to images, post the images.

Comment: @sagi i edited it, thanks.

Comment: Check is there any timestamp in `posts` table and order them by this column.

Comment: @mitkosoft unseccessful. this is result: [link](http://i.imgur.com/B1e11wl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this i assume created `column` is exist in `posts` table

```
 "SELECT users.ID, posts.ID 
  FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS posts
    JOIN  {$wpdb->users} AS users ON posts.post_author = users.ID 
   WHERE posts.post_type='post' AND posts.post_status='publish'
   GROUP BY users.ID 
   ORDER BY posts.created DESC 
   LIMIT %d"`
```

Comment: sorry, blank widget.

Comment: @sezeriltekin not understand blank widget

Comment: it sorts anormally: [link](http://i.imgur.com/B1e11wl.jpg) i think it try to sort as user id...

Comment: @sezeriltekin try my query

Comment: this is your query in phpmyadmin.

Comment: this is output: http://i.imgur.com/B1e11wl.jpg as you see, it sort as user.id not last post. ID 39,40,38,37,36,35,34...

Comment: @sezeriltekin edited a query this gives latest post id and user id

Comment: I understand you but It selects THE FIRST POST of each author and sort as this. We can not get the LAST POST with this code.

Comment: @sezeriltekin modify it.It selects the latest(last) post by each author